# AWS Amplify with Vue and GraphQL: stale data after authenticating

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, graphql, aws-amplify

Probably a question similar to this has been answered but I can't seem to get it resolved after much searching.
I'm trying to build a Vue app with AWS Amplify using security with Cognito user pools.
I've basically followed the steps in the tutorial here: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/vue.
I don't have a ton of web development experience, but I was happily moving along until I realized a problem that seems to be related to caching.

I noticed that components in my Vue app only load after refreshing the page in the browser.  So if the cache is clear with no user logged in, the the following behavior occurs:
 1. Navigate to the web URL.
 2. Login page correctly displays.
 3. Login and go to home page.
**4. Home page is blank!**
 5. Only after refreshing the page the user data is displayed.

*Or if a user is already logged in then the following occurs:
1. Log out current user.
2. Log in with a new user.
**3. The previous user data is still displayed!**
4. Only after refreshing the page the current user data is displayed.

The following is a simplified example.  This is my app.vue:

```
<template>
  <amplify-authenticator>
    <div id="app">
      <div id="nav">
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
        <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
      </div>
      <router-view />
    </div>
    <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
  </amplify-authenticator>
</template>
```

This is my home.vue:

```
<template>
  <div compRenderer>
    <h1>Welcome, {{ user.username }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {}
    };
  },
  async beforeCreate() {
    this.user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  }
};
</script>
```

After searching, I've tried using v-if to see if username is empty... I've tried using "watch"... I've tried a couple techniques described here: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/. Still, I can't get the application to retrieve the data before rendering the page.

I would think putting the call to Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser in the beforeCreate event would force it to finish before loading the page... or at least with async and await, the page would automatically update once the api call finished.  But it's not happening.

What am I doing wrong?

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and would really appreciate any help someone can give.

Comment: `beforeCreate` isn't inspiring? not reevaluated after mount ... use vuex? use react ;)

Comment: Hi @xadm... I do use Vuex in the app, but I don't think this has anything to do with that, does it?  Like I said, I don't have tons of experience with web development... but I've got some investment into Vue... with React I'd have to start over.

Comment: vuex should be used for auth as global state, not local, not refreshed, badly updated etc.

Comment: @xadm... In this post I stripped the Vuex functionality out in order to show the simplest example of my problem.  In this Vue component I was updating Vuex with the user information after pulling it from the auth API.  Are you saying that the auth API should instead be called from the Vuex store itself?  I couldn't really find an example like that... it seemed like in the examples I found any APIs are called from Vue itself and only data passed to Vuex. But I also didn't find tons of examples that seemed to fit my use case.

Comment: nooo, succesfull login (awaited) response should be used to dispatch user info to store. Logout should dispatch some action to clear this info in store. All components related to user info in store should be automatically refreshed with current (user or empty) info. It seams your app (store) is not properly updated. ... using `beforeCreate` doesn't look like good choice

Comment: Ah... ok... I'm using the standard login/logout from AWS Amplify.  I guess the only way to do what you're saying is to modify that.  Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: maybe it is a valid flow, it depends on structure - this looks very simple: https://gist.github.com/dabit3/dce3abb42d209a5d735af6f007af7d7a ?

Comment: simple vuex example: https://chaosgears.com/lets-start-developing-using-vue-and-amplify/